# How to have personalized and admin view to see list items?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

For one of the lists, I have applied grouping by Created By. The list basically shows items submitted by users as part of the form. What I want to do is, when a user is logged in, he/she should only be able to see his/her submitted items and then for one of the users (admin), I would want her to see the entries submitted by all the users in the organization.

Is there an easy work around for this? please help, thanks in advance.
FYI, I am working with SharePoint online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To make a view to show only user own submitted items\documents :**

1. go to Library\List Settings scroll down to views.
2. click on the default library\ List view.
3. Rename the view to a proper name.
4. scroll down to Filter section
5. Check **Show items only when the following is true:**
6. under **Show the items when column** Select **Created By** field.
7. Second drop down Select **is equal to**
8. in the textbox below write [Me]. 
   [image]

[image]

**To Create admin View for a specific Person:**

Administrator can create his\her own **Personal view**  ,

1. to do this should login with the administrator account.
2. go to Library\List Settings scroll down to views.
3. Click on Create View
4. in **Choose a view type** click on **Standard View** .
5. enter the view name
6. under the **View Audience:** choose **Create a Personal View**
7. Check the requited fields to be available in your view and **Save**.

[image]